# Recursive Class

Tags: python, pydantic

My use case forces me to build something like a recursive model.
For example, if I want to model file and folder from an OS system:

A folder can contain multiple folder and files, and the same apply recursively for folders inside a folder.
I  try to represent this in Python, I am using pydantic for modeling my schema :

```py
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel

class File(BaseModel):
     name: str

class Folder(BaseModel):
     folders : List[Folder]
     files: List[File]
     name: str
```

I am kind of struggle to represent the logic that a folder can contain multiple folder, and so on and so on.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: The class Folder, does not know itself. Thus List[Folder] brings errors in my IDE

Comment: See the linked duplicate for how to use a class in its own type hints. TLDR, in Python 3.10 + this will "just work". If you are using an earlier version, either use a string, or `from __future__ import annotations` for the upcoming behavior

Comment: And, for pydantic: https://prompt-build--pydantic-docs.netlify.app/#self-referencing-models

Comment: Perfect, thank you for the pointer, next time I will read more in depth the f... manual :)